# Parse a string with specific condition

Tags: ios, swift2

How can I trim my string which is in this form:

```
https://xxx.kflslfsk.com/kjjfkskfjksf/v1/files/media/93939393hhs8.jpeg
```

to this?

```
media/93939393hhs8.jpeg
```

I want to remove all the characters before the second to last slash `/`.

I can use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` but I don't know how to specify the condition that I want:

```
let trimmedString = myString.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(
  NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() // what here in my case ??
)
```

The above is for removing the white spaces, but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the string is an URL get the path components, remove anything but the last 2 items and join the items with the slash separator.

```
if let url = NSURL(string:"https://xxx.kflslfsk.com/kjjfkskfjksf/v1/files/media/93939393hhs8.jpeg"), pathComponents = url.pathComponents {
  let trimmedString = pathComponents.suffix(2).joinWithSeparator("/")
  print(trimmedString)
}
```

Comment: @vadian exactly what i needed , thanks a lot ,  appreciate your effort man

Comment: Cool. I knew about `NSURLComponents`, but not the `NSURL` property `pathComponents`. Thanks for teaching me a new trick. (Voted.)

Comment: I assume pathComponents trims away things like query strings?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, the `path` is everything between the `host` which is `xxx.kflslfsk.com` in the example and the query (`?`) separator

Answer (score 1):

You're not trimming, you're parsing.

There's no single call that will do what you want. I suggest writing a block of code that uses `componentsSeparatedByString("\n")` to break it into lines (one URL per line), then parse each line separately.

You could use `componentsSeparatedByString("/")` on each line to break it into the fragments between your slashes, and then assemble the last 2 fragments together.

(I'm deliberately not writing out the code for you. You should do that for yourself. I'm just pointing you in the right direction.)

You might also be able to use `NSURLComponents` to treat each line as a URL, but I'm not sure how you'd get the last part of URL before the filename (e.g. "media " or "lego") with that method.

Comment: @DunanC seems like my example was not clear enough its just a line of string (see the updated question ) , i putted extra lines for better understanding (it didn't helped though )  ***I'm just pointing you in the right direction*** its enough for me thanks for responding :) appreciate your effort man